# Increase re-heating oven temperature for cooked ham

Tags: ham

I have an 11 pound bone-in preparation cooked ham.

It says to cook at 325°F for 15-20 min per pound.

Can I increase the temperature to 350°F without drying it out in order to speed up the reheat time?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, 25 degrees extra shouldn't make a big difference to dryness. If you have an extra roasting bag, that'll help it stay moist. A gas oven will give you more moistness than an electric oven and you might get away with an even higher temperature. I doubt it'll make a big difference to the total time, though. In an emergency, the easiest way to quickly heat a pre-cooked ham is to slice it and use moist heat on the slices.

Comment: OK thank you! Its in a covered roasting pan with quarter inch of doctor pepper in a gas oven. I was just hoping to shave off a half hour or so.

Comment: *"A gas oven will give you more moistness than an electric oven"* why would that be the case?

Comment: @Molot because the gas oven’s combustion produces water vapor.